# Read/Write characteristic using custom service BLE in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect the **Thermometer** with an android device using BLE. I am getting proper results using Gatt characteristics specifications and services. but there is one custom service I am getting from the device.

CUSTOM service (`UUID = 00001523-1212-EFDE-1523-785FEABCD123`)

CUSTOM characteristic (`UUID = 00001524-1212-EFDE-1523-785FEABCD123`) [marked as `WRITE/INDICATE/NOTIFY` in smartphone app)

descriptor (`UUID = 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` marked as READ in smartphone app)

and listing several 8-byte commands to send to the meter waiting for an 8-byte response from it.

Commands are sent using a frame with this format below :

```
[0x51 0x26 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xA3 CHK-SUM]
```

where the checksum is the summation of 1..7 byte.

but How to send this command?

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
                     

    req_frame[0] = (byte) 0x51;
    req_frame[1] = (byte) 0x26;
    req_frame[2] = (byte) 0x00;
    req_frame[3] = (byte) 0x00;
    req_frame[4] = (byte) 0x00;
    req_frame[5] = (byte) 0x00;
    req_frame[6] = (byte) 0xA3;
    req_frame[7] = (byte) 0xE6;
                        characteristic.setValue(buffer);
                        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
                        peripheral.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, buffer, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
```

OnCharacteristicWrite gives response success. but onCharacteristicChanged not called.

How to work with this type of Protocol?

Comment: Hello Rushita, I try read string from BLE device but failed to read. Can you help me to resolved my issue.